# Create Automation Button is missing

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

The "Create Automation" button couldn't be found in Automation Studio overview page, but I could find the "Create Activity" button. Does it mean I don't have the right to create automation?

[image: Automation Studio Overview]
[image: Automation Studio - Create Activity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the `Create, Edit, Execute` permission hides the button `New Automation`, so you need to ask an Admin to enable a new role or permission for you. You can find [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_automation_studio_roles.htm&type=5) what default roles have access to Automation Studio's features.

[image]

Note to remember when working with roles and permissions -

> An explicitly denied permission always overrides all other permissions. When a permission is not explicitly granted or denied, Marketing Cloud defaults to a deny permission unless another role grants that permission.

You can also see that rule working on the screenshot, where I have "MC Admin" role but then still got overwritten with `Deny` value.